# Retrieve List of Cells in Excel Where Column Equals Something

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to do something in Excel without using VBA macros.  I suspect it is possible, but have some up empty so far.  Basically for values in a table, I'd like to retrieve a list of all values in Column A conditionally where Column B equals a value I provide.

For example I'd like a function that essentially returns a range/description of cells for Column A if Column B is equal to zero.

```
Column A  Column B
   1          0
   2          0
   3          1
   4          0
```

would return a range describing cells a2, a3, and a5 (1, 2, 4).  I'd prefer to be able to do this using a formula, and not manually using pivot tables.  I would be willing to create a view of the data using pivot tables if that table could then be referenced via a function to give me the appropriate results.  I am also able to sort Column B in any way if it makes it easier to do this.

Ultimately I need to pull out a random value from Column A that meet the criteria of Column B in case that matters in the final solution.

Thanks.

Comment: A pivot table is certainly one solution, but why not just use the Autofilter? That said, if you insist on formulas and not VBA, then try the solution I provided.

Comment: Thanks.  I need to automate a much more complicated task for people and i great prefer the copy and paste method to the implementing this.  I actually used something that looks similar to =OFFSET(Campaigns!$A$1,RANDBETWEEN(MATCH(B2,Table2[[#All],[Advertiser ID]],0), MATCH(B2,Table2[[#All],[Advertiser ID]],1))-1,0), where I ensure the proper sorting of the tables.  Not the most elegent soluiton, but it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array formula.

Type in:

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$4,SMALL(IF($C$1=$B$1:$B$4,ROW($B$1:$B$4)),ROW(1:1)),1)`

then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Drag and fill the cells below until `#NUM!` shows up. This formula assumes the value you're looking for is in `C1` and there are no headers (data starts in 1st row rather than 2nd).

Comment: hi, I am trying something similar. Can I use the `countif` function with the above formula as `criteria`?

Comment: How do I get more than the first column?

Comment: This is a really helpful answer. To improve it further would it be possible for someone who understands it to post an explanation of why and how it works?